# Aproximating $E[g(X)]$ using Monte Carlo method

Tags: expected-value, monte-carlo, simulation

In an exercise, my teacher asked to approximate the expected value of $g(X)$ where X is a  random variable with probability density function $f(x)$ using the Monte Carlo method.
I thought about it, and came up with two ways of doing this:

---

1. 

Using $f(x)$ I can calculate the cumulative probability function $F(x)$ of $X$. Then I can simulate a large amount of numbers $\{u_i\}_1^n$ with distribution $U(0,1)$ and using the inverse function method, I can calculate $x_i=F^{-1}(u_i)$ and thus $\{x_i\}_i^n$ will be a set of numbers with distribution $X$. Then we can estimate $$E[g(X)]\simeq\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^ng(x_i)$$

---

2. 

We know that the expected value is given by the integral $$E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x)dx$$
Using a change of variable, I was able to find an equivalent integral $$\int_0^1h(x)dx$$

Now, this integral is equal to $E[h(U)]$ where $U$ has uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. We can simulate $\{u_i\}_1^n$ with distribution $U(0,1)$ and then approximate the integral as: $$E[g(X)]=\int_0^1h(x)dx\simeq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nh(u_i)$$

---

My questions are: Are both these methods correct? If so, are they equivalent or is one better then the other in estimating the expected value?

Comment: I may answer your first question. Your second question does not address what *better* means, so I can't address it. Are you interested?

Comment: By better I mean produce, on average, more accurate approximations. which estimator has the lowest variance? @Snoop

Comment: I think it might be useful to write $f,g,h$ explicitly then.

Comment: But I'm more interested in the general case. That way I know which method to chose next time I encounter this type of exercise with a different $g,f$. Is that possible? @Snoop